# .bat deleting subdirectories unintentionally

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, command-prompt

```
pushd "\\svr01\folderA\"     
forfiles /P . /D -2 /C "cmd /C del /Q @path && cmd /c echo [%DATE%%TIME%] Deleted file @path" >> %LOGFILE%    
popd
```

Why is this deleting the content of my subdirectories? :F 
I thought it wouldn't unless I included a "/S" in the command

It seems "IF @ISDIR==FALSE echo" is the fix?

```
forfiles /P . /D -2 /C "cmd /C IF @ISDIR==FALSE del /Q @path && cmd /c echo [%DATE%%TIME%] Deleted file @path" >> %LOGFILE%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not delete the whole content of a directory, but it will delete all *files* within the directory.

To quote the `DEL` help:

> DEL [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names
>
> names:         Specifies a list of one or more files or directories.
>                   Wildcards may be used to delete multiple files. **If a
>                   directory is specified, all files within the directory
>                   will be deleted.**

**Edit:** Yes, the `@isdir` check allows you to avoid this issue.

Comment: But I don't specify /S yet it deletes files in the subdirectory

Comment: Suppose you have a directory with junk files `c:\junk`. If you do `DEL /Q c:\junk`, all **files** inside the directory will be gone, but neither subdirectories nor their contents. `/S` is for recursing into other, non-specified folders beneath the specified one.

Comment: Oh, I thought no /s would automatically ignoring files within subfolders :| so "IF @ISDIR" should prevent the deletions? Luckily there's versioning on the folders! :x

Comment: Actually, I could imagine the `@isdir` check exists for precisely such situations as the one you are in :)

Answer (score 0):

[`DEL` Delete one or more files.](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html)

> If a folder name is given instead of a file, all files in the folder
>   will be deleted, but the folder itself will not be removed.

Check using `if /I "@isdir"=="FALSE"` as follows:

```
forfiles /P . /D -2 /C "cmd /C if /I "@isdir"=="FALSE" (del /Q @path && echo [%DATE% %TIME%] Deleted file @fdate @path")
```